# Keras/Theano output

Tags: python, theano, keras

I'm struggling with theano types.

I created some `Sequential` model in Keras, where the last layer is

```
final_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

When I try

```
final_model.get_output([x,x])
>>> sigmoid.0
```

How can I get get the actual output number?
I tried using `output.eval()` resp. `output[0][0].eval()`
but that results only in

`theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: ("An input of the graph, used to compute Shape(<TensorType(int32, matrix)>), was not provided and not given a value.Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high',for more information on this error.", <TensorType(int32, matrix)>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't drown on a glass of water.

You can just use final_model.predict(input) to get an array of predictions, given an array of input values. Just note that this function can be used to predict more than set of input values.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed